# Why isn't `model.fit` defined in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am following step 3 of [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/01/scikit-learn-python-machine-learning-tool/) example:

```
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)

expected = dataset.target

predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)
```

I don't understand why scikit doesn't recognize `model.fit`.

Do I need assign that variable first? 
Is there a missing import?

I'm working in jupyter, scikit-learn 0.17.1.

Comment: You need to define the model first - you can't fit an undefined model. You should probably find a better tutorial

Comment: Assuming that you try to do logit regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do a logistical regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first initiate an instance of whatever model you're using:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()    
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fit(x,y)` is a method that can be used on an estimator.

In order to be able to use this method on `model` you would have to create model first and make sure its of an estimator class.

[Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html)